# How can I edit top_block.py so that the frequency constantly and randomly sets between two values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have this simple flowgraph:
[image]

That generated this top_block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Not titled yet
# Author: alessandro
# GNU Radio version: 3.8.1.0

from distutils.version import StrictVersion

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ctypes
    import sys
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        try:
            x11 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')
            x11.XInitThreads()
        except:
            print("Warning: failed to XInitThreads()")

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
import sys
import signal
from PyQt5 import Qt
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gnuradio.eng_arg import eng_float, intx
from gnuradio import eng_notation
import osmosdr
import time
from gnuradio import qtgui

class test(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Not titled yet")
        Qt.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Not titled yet")
        qtgui.util.check_set_qss()
        try:
            self.setWindowIcon(Qt.QIcon.fromTheme('gnuradio-grc'))
        except:
            pass
        self.top_scroll_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.top_scroll_layout)
        self.top_scroll = Qt.QScrollArea()
        self.top_scroll.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.top_scroll_layout.addWidget(self.top_scroll)
        self.top_scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.top_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.top_scroll.setWidget(self.top_widget)
        self.top_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.top_widget)
        self.top_grid_layout = Qt.QGridLayout()
        self.top_layout.addLayout(self.top_grid_layout)

        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "test")

        try:
            if StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) < StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry").toByteArray())
            else:
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry"))
        except:
            pass

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 2000000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.osmosdr_sink_0 = osmosdr.sink(
            args="numchan=" + str(1) + " " + ""
        )
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_time_unknown_pps(osmosdr.time_spec_t())
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_sample_rate(samp_rate)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_center_freq(100e6, 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_freq_corr(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_gain(10, 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_if_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_bb_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_antenna('', 0)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_bandwidth(0, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_c(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 1000, 1, 0, 0)



        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.osmosdr_sink_0, 0))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "test")
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())
        event.accept()

    def get_samp_rate(self):
        return self.samp_rate

    def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(self.samp_rate)
        self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_sample_rate(self.samp_rate)



def main(top_block_cls=test, options=None):

    if StrictVersion("4.5.0") <= StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) < StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
        style = gr.prefs().get_string('qtgui', 'style', 'raster')
        Qt.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem(style)
    qapp = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.start()
    tb.show()

    def sig_handler(sig=None, frame=None):
        Qt.QApplication.quit()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)

    timer = Qt.QTimer()
    timer.start(500)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)

    def quitting():
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
    qapp.aboutToQuit.connect(quitting)
    qapp.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't know how could I make osmocom Sink to transmit in two frequencies that are choosen randomly and constantly.

Should I put a while cycle? The fact is that I tried several things, but nothing works, so I really don't know how can I do that.

I'd like to choose randomly between two frequencies, so something like this:

```
freqs = [100000000,200000000]

while 1:
    freq = random.choice(freqs)
    # then osmocom transmits in "freq"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you'd want is not `random.choice`, but rather `random.randrange` (and some list unpacking so you can use your input list as arguments passed to a function). `random.randrange(x, y)` works the same as doing `random.choice(range(x, y))`, but is a bit more efficient about it. Here's a [link to the documentation on it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

If you're going for a random frequency between your min and max, your code should look more like this:

```
freqs = [100000000,200000000]

while True:
  # Doing *freqs unpacks the list so you can use it as
  # arguments to random.randrange
  freq = random.randrange(*freqs)
  # your other code stuff
```

I'm not sure why you put the other code there when the randomization seems to be your only issue. If that's relevant to the issue at hand, then I'm going to have to ask that you clarify the question, because as it's phrased now, it looks like that's it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually my problem wasn't the randomization. It was that I don't know where to put the randomization part code to have a working code.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I'd need a little more clarification on exactly what it is you're trying to do. If you're trying to get it to constantly choose a random frequency, you'd put it within the `while` loop; otherwise, if what you want to do is have a random frequency that remains constant, you'll want to use it outside of the loop.